# How to get vars out of a looped html form?

Tags: php, html

I got a html form which i loop like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  echo '<input type="text" name="field'.$i.'">';
}
```

then i make and hidden input with a count var which says that there are 10 such input fields. but now i hav `$field0` to `$field9` and i do not know how i can get the input in a for loop again.

thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use names like this in your input fields: `...'field['.$i.']'...`

This way in your $_POST these will show up in an array for you, and you can loop over them like:

```
foreach ($_POST['field'] as $key => $value)
{

}
```

Comment: this sounds very easy :) i like that!

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should use $_POST to get your form data. then you can make this by doing

```
for($i=0;$i<$_POST["count"];$i++) {
  $var = $_GET["field".$i];
  //do something
}
```

I assume that you have a count variable in `$_POST["count"]`
2nd you could better use Arrays in your looped form

```
<input type="text" name="field[0]">
```

then you have an array in `$_POST["field"]` with `$_POST["field"][0]` and `$_POST["field"][1]` etc...

but to answer just you wanted you can also use variable variables:
here a sample which should make this clear

```
$a1 = "What";
$a2 = " are";
$a3 = " you";
$a4 = " doing?";
for($i=1;$i<=4;$i++){ 
  $txt .= ${"a".$i}; 
  echo $txt;
}
```

takes as output

> "What are you doing?"

:)

Comment: i think you should have the choise. But as I said please use $_POST :)

Answer (score 2):

in your loop:

```
echo '<input type="text" name="field['.$i.']">';
```

then when you process this form when it's submitted:

```
$fields = $_POST['field'];
```

the "field" variable will be sent as an array to PHP